# URLFOR statement in outputLink to direct to object creation page

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, record-type, outputlink, urlfor

So I want to put a button on a visualforce page that when pushed it will redirect the user to a new custom object page. However, this custom object has 4 various Record Types. I can construct the URLFOR to redirect to the following page and have the correct record type prepopulated in the field
[image]

The URLFOR statement that I am using is this:

```
<apex:outputLink style="font-size:125%" styleClass="btn" target="_top" value="{!URLFOR($Action.Relationship_Detail__c.New, null, [p3='012o0000000I2ie'])}">
```

What I would like that whenever I click the link it automatically pushes that continue button so that I can get to the actual creation page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `save=1` parameter to continue through the Record Type screen automatically.

In your example code the URLFOR function would look like:

```
value="{!URLFOR($Action.Relationship_Detail__c.New, null, [p3='012o0000000I2ie', save=1])}"
```

Comment: I can see that you've already received this exact same answer on a question which you asked yesterday. Instead of creating a new question, I would suggest editing the other question and providing more details if the provided answer does not solve the problem.